# Lambda filter to exclude strings

Tags: python, string, list, filter, lambda

I have a list in which I would like to add the filter. The filter in question should include specific words beyond the position in the string. However, I would also like to exclude certain words in the filter.
This is the code I am using:

```
L_Glue = list(filter(lambda x:  'Glue' or 'Adhesive' in x, mat_paths["PLASTER"]))
```

For example, I would like all strings that have the word "Plaster" in them to be excluded from the list.
I would also like the search to be independent of the letter type (upper or lower case).

Comment: `'Glue' in x or 'Adhesive' in x`

Comment: thank you. This is certainly correct. But how can I exclude the term "Plaster" from the solution?

Comment: `('Glue' in x or 'Adhesive' in x) and 'Plaster' not in x`

Comment: Hi Barmar, How can I exclude the sensitive case for uppercase,lowercase letters

Comment: `'glue' in x.lower() or 'adhesive' in x.lower()`

Comment: Or use a regexp: `re.search(r'glue|adhesive', x, flags=re.I)`